# Javascript string.match refuses to return an array of more than one match

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string that I expect to be formatted like so:

`{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}`

My query looks like this in javascript:

```
var str = "{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}";
var result = str.match(/^\{List:\[Names:([a-zA-z,]*)\]\[Ages:([0-9,]*)\]\}$/g);
```

*Note: I recognize that with this regex it would pass with something like "Ages:,,,", but I'm not worried about that at the moment.*

I was expecting to get this back:

```
result[0] = "{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}"
result[1] = "a,b,c"
result[2] = "1,2,3"
```

But no matter what I seem to do to the regular expression, it refuses to return an array of more than one match, I just get the full string back (because it passes, which is a start):

```
result = ["{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}"]
```

I've looked through a bunch of questions on here already, as well as other 'intro' articles, and none of them seem to address something this basic. I'm sure it's something foolish that I've overlooked, but I truly have no idea what it is :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is a difference in how the global flag is applied in Regular Expressions in JavaScript.

In `.match`, the global flag (`/g` at the end) will return an array of every incident where the regular expression matches the string. Without that flag, `.match` will return an array of all of the groupings in the string.

eg:

```
var str = "{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}";
str += str;
// removed ^ and $ for demonstration purposes
var results = str.match(/\{List:\[Names:([a-zA-z,]*)\]\[Ages:([0-9,]*)\]\}/g)
console.log(results)
// ["{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}", "{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}"]
str = "{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:3,4,5]}";
results = str.match(/\{List:\[Names:([a-zA-z,]*)\]\[Ages:([0-9,]*)\]\}/g);
console.log(results)
//["{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}", "{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:3,4,5]}"]
```

Now, if we remove that `/g` flag:

```
// leaving str as above
results = str.match(/\{List:\[Names:([a-zA-z,]*)\]\[Ages:([0-9,]*)\]\}/);
console.log(results)
//["{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}", "a,b,c", "1,2,3"]
```

And as a note as to why `regex.exec` worked, [that is because:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the same result as regexp.exec(string).

Comment: Yep, that's certainly it (facepalm). So, to be clear, it makes no sense whatsoever, in any circumstance, to use groupings and /g with .match, correct?

Comment: That depends. You can query each of the results of the regex to get more information.

Comment: Ah, I see. But because I had ^ and $ in there, for start/end of string, it makes no sense to use /g. Gotcha! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, no, it doesn't there.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the form `needle.exec(haystack)`

From my console:

```
> haystack = "{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}";
"{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}"

> needle = /^\{List:\[Names:([a-zA-z,]*)\]\[Ages:([0-9,]*)\]\}$/g ;
/^\{List:\[Names:([a-zA-z,]*)\]\[Ages:([0-9,]*)\]\}$/g

> needle.exec(haystack);
["{List:[Names:a,b,c][Ages:1,2,3]}", "a,b,c", "1,2,3"]
```

Comment: The RegExp `exec()` and String `match()` methods are essentially the same, with the roles of receiver and parameter reversed.

Comment: @Pointy Not Quite, according to [Mozilla's Spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match): *If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matches. If there were no matches, the method returns null.*